# What part of speech is 'echoes' when not a noun plural?

Tags: parts-of-speech

For example in the sentence: "I will say it loud enough so that it echoes"
What part of speech is 'echoes'? Would it become a verb or an adverb?

Comment: This is probably a question for the English learners and teachers stackexchange ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ELL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Echoes' is not plural here; it is a third-person singular verb.

An adverb cannot take a plural marker in English:

(1) *They go hastilies.

In addition, an adverb modifies an adjective, adverb or verb in English. In this sentence, 'echoes' is a predicate and is not modifying an adjective, adverb or verb, thus we should not consider it an adverb.

By contrast, the verb is the only category in English which can head a predicate. It can also take the -s marker, which expresses the third person and singular number of the subject. This is a type of subject-verb agreement, which in turn is a kind of head-marking. It marks the grammatical relationship of 'subject' between the subject 'it' and the verb 'echo'.